# How to find the sum of the first n terms of the Geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question is in my test book. I want to know that how to solve it. Can any one help me out?

**Q: Find the sum of the first n terms of the this series:
.7+.77+.777+...........**.

Comment: This series isn't quite geometric.  There's no common ratio.

Comment: you mean 0.7+0.77+0.777? What is this dot before each number?

Comment: @Stefanos That is a decimal point.  Often the $0$ is omitted before the decimal point.

Comment: yes exactly. dot means the decimal point.

Comment: The bold font lifts the decimal point to an odd place, which makes it look more like $\cdot 7 + \cdot 77 + \cdots$ than $.7 + .77 + \ldots$.

Comment: @Goos Yes, I know that it is sometimes omitted, was not sure though. Thanks, for answering :)

Comment: So how to find out the sum?

Answer (score 5):

The desired sum equals
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{7}{10^i}
&= \frac{7}{10} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1 - \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{k}}{1 - \frac{1}{10}} \\
&= \frac{7}{10} \frac{10}{9} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[1 - \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{k} \right] \\
&= \frac{7}{9} \left[ n - \frac{1}{10} \left( \frac{1 - \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{n}}{1 - \frac{1}{10}}\right) \right]\\
&= \frac{7}{9} \left[ n - \frac{1}{9} \left( {1 - \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{n}}\right) \right]\\
&= \frac{7}{9} n - \frac{7}{81} + \frac{7}{81} \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^n  \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Beautiful ! Thanks.

Comment: @gammatester Give me a second, I'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, writing things as formulas often helps. Can you write down a formula for the $n$-th term?

Comment: Formula for find the sum of Geometric series is:

Comment: Find a formula for the $n$-th term before you try to figure out how to actually add them all!

Comment: Sn = a(1-r^n)/(1-r)

Comment: @zonnie: My mistake: I thought you wanted "help", rather than someone to do the problem for you.

Comment: I  have done with this problem with the same formula which i have written in above comment. thanks Hurkhyl.